# Adding --ignore-failed-read to tar causes "unknown function modifier" error

Tags: unix, backup, tar

I'm using the tar command in UNIX to perform backups of particular directories. However, some directories contain files/sub-directories which the current user doesn't have any read permissions on. As a result the tar command is returning a non 0 exit code.

I came across the following modifier in the man pages '--ignore-failed-read', which suppresses the non 0 exit code when encountering files it cannot read. However, whenever I try using it I get the error 'unknown function modifier'.

Could anyone help me out here?

my tar command looks something like this:

```
tar --create --ignore-failed-read --file=test.tar my_dir
```

Comment: This isn't a good question for stackoverflow.  It has been flagged so hopefully it will get moved to a more appropriate SE site for you.

Comment: You can try `tar --ignore-failed-read -cf test.tar my_dir`, it's probably just the order of the arguments.

Comment: bsdtar 3.3.2 (macOS 10.15.5) does not have this option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your command seems to be perfectly valid and I don't see any typos/mistakes.
To be absolutely sure, I just tried it on my VM running under 32 bit Debian 7.1 (wheezy) with stock kernel 3.2.0.4. As I suspected, archive has been created successfuly (the only change was, of course, the name of the source directory). I also checked version of my tar with

```
tar --version
```

which gave me following output:

```
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

First of all, you should check this info. If you get the same (with possible difference in version number) output, that's fine. If not (or version that seems much older), it's possible, that you are using tar, which simply doesn't support this feature.

Also, you can check, if your tar really DOES support mentioned flag. To do this, type into console:

```
tar --help | grep ignore-failed-read
```

You should see something like this:

```
--ignore-failed-read   do not exit with nonzero on unreadable files
```

If output stays empty, that means this version of tar does not know this flag at all.

See if any of the above helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the version of tar on the system I work with doesn't support this modifier... Unfortunitly!

Answer (score 2):

Another option that might work better in this case is `--warning=no-file-changed`.

```
tar --warning=no-file-changed -czf backup.tgz dir1 dir2
```

`--warning` controls the display of warning messages. You can add `no-` to the message keyword to suppress it. So in this case `no-file-changed` suppresses the `file-changed` warning.

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_27.html